# Приближение фонового изображения

Tags: css3

Хочу сделать приближение фонового изображения, как например на сайте у Сбербанка Онлайн.https://online.sberbank.ru/CSAFront/index.do

Пусть фон начинает приближаться при размере экрана 882px и появляются полосы прокрутки. Но моя попытка не работает должным образом. Фон не приближается красиво, сверху и снизу появляются области без картинки.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url('https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 882px) {
  body {
    background-size: unset;
  }
}
```

Как добиться желаемого, какими свойствами?

**EDIT1**

Исправлена ссылка на пример.

**EDIT2**

Добавлен скрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш пример не открывается, приведите другой. По поводу вашего css - если вы пишете сначала background-[option]: ..., то следующий background перезаписывает все background-[option].

Comment: Да, это понятно что свойство перезаписывается, но как его перезаписать должным образом, или может вообще не background-size изменить надо, а какое-то другое свойство.

Comment: Поменять их местами

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-size: 100%;
  background: url('https://s1.1zoom.ru/big0/34/322924-alexfas01.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 882px) {
  body {
    background-size: 200%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 582px) {
  body {
    background-size: 300%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Но так при уменьшении экрана фон не приближается, а уменьшается. Сверху и снизу  области без изображения.

Comment: Это не прямой ответ... Это я к тому, что `background-size: N%;` можно задавать еще и проценты...  А как тебе надо именно ты сам без труда сделаешь.... Задай в место `background-size: 80%;` - `background-size: 300%;`  и увидешь разницу

Comment: Даже если я задам 300%, при уменьшении экрана фон уменьшается, а чтобы он увеличивался, придется написать много мадиа запросов. Чем меньше экран тем больше процент я задаю соответственно в медиа запросе. Насколько такой способ оптимален?

Comment: @lipton_v, пробуй разными возможными единицами  измерения `CSS`,  просто не могу знать, что да как именно ты хочешь...   И да-да... `@madia` для этого и существует